# Testing in JUnit to verify that excpetion is caught on the right heirarchy level

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit

I have a serie of classes that call each other and propogate an exception. I want to write a test in JUnit that verifies that the exception was caught on the right level and not before-hand.

How can I do that?

For example if I have:
class A throws exception
class B (called A) throws exception
class C (called B) catches the exception

If someone caught the exception in class B I wish the test to fail.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can check that class B always throws the exception with `assertThrows()`:

```
@Test
void shouldThrowException() {
    Assertions.assertThrows(YourException.class, () -> {
        b.executeMethod();
    });
}
```

Additionally you can mock class A to throw exception when its method is called, so your test will check that B always throws the exception when A throws it

Comment: But how can I verify it is not caught eariler?

Comment: If B class still throws the exception, it should mean that it was not caught earlier.
Also, maybe you can look at the exception stack trace to verify, where it was initially thrown. If you have hierarchy classes A, B, C, D and somehow need to check all the chain, you can get the exception from D and check that A, B, C are part of the stack trace